# Contour Plot in Spherical coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, visualization

There is a  `ContourPlot3D`in Cartesian coordinates, and afik none in dealing with implicit functions in spherical coordinates.

EDIT1:

If provided the spherical plot could define a surface of coaxal cones/surface intersections $\phi =$const;  surface/ layered sphere intersection lines $ r=$ const;  surface/ several radial pie cuts $ \theta= $ const...

which are visible on the surface under discussion analogously to ContourPlot3D , plotted *directly* with chosen intervals in $(r, \theta, \phi).$

That is,

just as intersection marks are left outside on any surface plotted for Cartesian coordinates $(x=const, y= const, z=const)$ in ContourPlot3D,

so also intersection marks should be left on any surface plotted for Spherical coordinates $(\phi=const, \theta= const,r=const)$.

Imagined implicit intersections somewhat like,

```
ContourPlot3DSph[ (r + Sin[phi - theta]) (r* theta+2)==0, {phi,.5,3}, {theta,0,3}, {r,1,2}]
```

I understand there is no such plot function available now..

There may be separate code or Cartesian related short cuts. Thanks for all indications.

Comment: Well... this isn't quite a ContourPlot.  In a ContourPlot you specify a *scalar* function and the number of contours you desire, and the contours are displayed.  There is no specification of the form `f[.,.,.] == 0`, and most certainly never wrapped in brackets.  If you have a *specific* function, perhaps we can help.

Comment: Scalar here also, analogously. The intersection is with several cone nappes of different $\phi$  values, $r=$ const cylinder intersections  , pie segments $\theta = 0, \pi/6$  by radial cuts and  so on. The Cartesian ContourPlot3D level contours  are defined by intersecting planes of infinite radii of curvature by  $(x,y,z)-$ spacing /intervals chosen by default for level lines.

Comment: r=  const is the spherical intersections instead of cylinder intersections  since it is the spherical coordinate,not the cylinder coordinate.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out, that was my error hope obvious, so  re-edited the full post.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a ContourPlot3Din Cartesian coordinates, and afik none in
> dealing with implicit functions in spherical coordinates.

From the documentation page:

```
SphericalPlot3D[
 1 + Sin[5 \[Phi]] Sin[10 \[Theta]]/10, {\[Theta], 0, Pi}, {\[Phi], 0,
   2 Pi}]
```

[image]

-------------------------------------------------- EDIT 16Aug2021

There is no SphericalContourPlot3D. I am not sure whether you want contours in spherical coordinates too, or in Cartesian coordinates, but take a look at the following page and the Application section as well. I searched through the names of all functions for 'contour'.

[SliceContourPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html)

[image]

A prior related post is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240483/plot-a-contour-of-concentration-profile-for-a-sphere).

Answer (score 1):

- Here we change some condition to illustrate the full situation.

```
eqn = TransformedField[
   "Spherical" -> 
    "Cartesian", (r*θ - 2) (r + Sin[ϕ - θ]) == 
    0 , {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}];
contrains = 
  TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
   0 < r < 2 && 0 < θ < 3 && 
    0.5 < ϕ < 3 , {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}];
ContourPlot3D[
 eqn // Evaluate, {x, y, z} ∈ 
  ImplicitRegion[contrains, {x, y, z}], RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 20, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

- Another way which is not so effective.

```
trans[r_, θ_, ϕ_] = 
  CoordinateTransform[
   "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, θ, ϕ}];
reg = ParametricRegion[{trans[
     r, θ, ϕ], (r*θ - 2) (r + 
        Sin[ϕ - θ]) == 0 }, {{r, 0, 2}, {θ, 0, 
     3}, {ϕ, 0.5, 3}}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> .0001];
RegionPlot3D[dreg, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]